# Syncing GitHub repo with Azure DevOps using YAML pipeline: How to fix 'pathspec did not match' error?

Tags: azure, github, devops, pipeline

**I am trying to run a pipeline to sync my github repository with my azure devops repository.**

I am using the following yaml code:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
  - checkout: self

  - script: |
      git config user.email "{My Email}"
      git config user.name "{Username}"
      # Add your commands to update the repository here
      git checkout main
      git add .
      git commit -m "Update from GitHub push"
    displayName: 'Update Azure DevOps Repo'

  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        git remote add azure https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_git/TestPipeLine.git
        git push azure HEAD:main
    env:
      GIT_CREDENTIALS: $(System.AccessToken)
    displayName: 'Push changes to Azure DevOps'
```

**I am getting the following error:**

```
2023-05-26T13:33:23.9031433Z ##[section]Starting: Update Azure DevOps Repo
2023-05-26T13:33:23.9036365Z ==============================================================================
2023-05-26T13:33:23.9036646Z Task         : Command line
2023-05-26T13:33:23.9036743Z Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
2023-05-26T13:33:23.9036898Z Version      : 2.212.0
2023-05-26T13:33:23.9037009Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2023-05-26T13:33:23.9037181Z Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
2023-05-26T13:33:23.9037366Z ==============================================================================
2023-05-26T13:33:24.3393907Z Generating script.
2023-05-26T13:33:24.3395036Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2023-05-26T13:33:24.3397948Z [command]/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/f8cfbbd0-3516-42fc-a1ce-d1998ad2f8e4.sh
2023-05-26T13:33:24.3398333Z error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git
2023-05-26T13:33:24.3398913Z HEAD detached at origin/39311dc6b93af464891335768515fe0573ac6442
2023-05-26T13:33:24.3399198Z nothing to commit, working tree clean
2023-05-26T13:33:24.3425900Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
2023-05-26T13:33:24.3467536Z ##[section]Finishing: Update Azure DevOps Repo
```

How do i fix it ?

I am trying to run a pipeline to sync my github repository with my azure devops repository.

Comment: You checkout to main, why do you need to run "git push azure HEAD:main"? Can you try with "git push azure main" only?